# How to align two div next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want two divs next to each other . one contains a button the other some text. i would like the text before the button with som margin. But the keep ending up on the wrong side.
 My code:

```css
.helpButton {
        display: inline-block;  
        float: right;
    }

    .helpText {
        margin-right: 5em;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .help-block {

        display: inline-block;  
        overflow: auto;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
                <div class="helpText">@Resource.FooterHelp</div>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">@Resource.FooterHelpLink</button>
            </div>
```

I know there are similar questions like this here on this forum, but cant get theme to work for me

> Thank you all for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<div>` to `<span>` and you'll save on lots of CSS:

```css
.helpText {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.help-block {
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <span class="helpText">Some text</span>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont' use floats (right floats reverses therorder of the elements). As you are using `display: inline-block`, a simple tex-align will work

```css
.help-block {

    display: inline-block;  
    text-align: right
}

.helpButton {
    display: inline-block;
}

.helpText {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="helpText">Some text</div>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flexbox and avoid floats. This way, all elements will follow the document flow (and you need less CSS code).

```css
.helpText {
  margin-right: 5em;
}

.help-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="helpText">@Resource.FooterHelp</div>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">@Resource.FooterHelpLink</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Logically you need to put `button` element before the `text` element because for both we are using `float:right`. So first it will put text in right and then button.So avoid this thing we just need to exchange the element sequence. No need to do any changes in css.

```css
.helpButton {
  float: right;
}

.helpText {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}


}
.help-block {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
     <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
  <div class="helpText">Some text</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display of the container element, which is .help-block in your case, from `inline-block` to `flex` will do the trick.
At least, if this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
.help-block {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```css
.helpButton {
  float: right;
}

.helpText {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.help-block {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="helpText">Some text</div>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inline-flex`,

```css
.helpButton {
  float: right;
}

.helpText {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
}


.help-block {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="helpText">Some text</div>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.helpButton {
  float: left;
}

.helpText {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
 
}


}
.help-block {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="helpText">Some text</div>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal" class="btn btn-default helpButton">Buttom</button>
</div>
```