# Offset child divs

Tags: html, css

```css
.titlebar {
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.slogan {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
}

.assets {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"> 
        </head>
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div class="assets">
                123
            </div>
            <div class="slogan">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

When adding more than one child to a parent div, the positions start offsetting. How can I make them level? I've tried vertical-align in both the children and the parents, but they remain offset.

Comment: `divs` are block elements. They aren't offsetting as much as doing what they are supposed to - starting after the previous block element. If you want them to align vertically, you need to use something like `display: flex` on the parent element. You may Google other solutions, and you'll find answers using `float` **please do not use `float`** It is an outdated positioning property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align two div next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296575/how-to-align-two-div-next-to-each-other) - use the flexbox example, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because both `div`s come one after another; they take up space in the normal document flow. If you want them both in the same position, you could either

1. Set the parent div to have `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` (**recommended solution**):

```css
.titlebar {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: top;
  
  /*  */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slogan {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.assets {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="assets">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="slogan">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

2. Add absolute positioning to both children (**not recommended** for your current situation, since absolute positioning removes elements from the normal document flow):

```css
.titlebar {
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.slogan {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
    
    /*  */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.assets {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
    
    /*  */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"> 
        </head>
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div class="assets">
                123
            </div>
            <div class="slogan">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate answer does answer this, but to answer your specific issue:

I changed your `.titlebar` to be a `flex` parent (no reason in your code to be `inline`), and set the `justify-content: space-between` property.

```css
.titlebar {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  /* changed this */
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: top;
  /* added this */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slogan {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

.assets {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="assets">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="slogan">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```